# Can I join POCO objects with Entities

Tags: entity-framework-6, linqpad

If I have a list of objects who have a property that should match the value of a field of an entity, can I use this in a join like this  (using linqpad for testing):

For some reason I think this is not going to work as it gets translated to sql. The query seems to take a long time in Linqpad and the sql that gets translated (at least that I can see) while its trying to execute doesnt seem to include anything about "dlist".

```
void Main()
{
    var dlist = new List<dor>();
    dlist.Add(new dor() {DeliveryScheduleID=223422});
    dlist.Add(new dor() {DeliveryScheduleID=223423});
    dlist.Add(new dor() {DeliveryScheduleID=223424});
    dlist.Add(new dor() {DeliveryScheduleID=223425});

var retval = (from a in dlist 
    join b in DeliverySchedules on a.DeliveryScheduleID equals b.Id
    join c in CustomerOrders on b.CustomerOrderID equals c.ID 
    select a.ID).Count ();  

retval.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class dor {

    public int DeliveryScheduleID {get;set;}

}
```

Comment: *For some reason I think this is not going to work as it gets translated to sql* You think it right. Not only that the joins with in memory collections are not supported, but also any query started with `IEnumerable<T>` goes through `Enumerable` (and not `Queryable`) extension methods, hence is executed in memory.

Comment: To follow on from what Ivan has said, because you start from dlist which is not Queryable the linq query **works** but slowly as it is executed in memory. If you had started from DeliverySchedules  it would have attempted to get SQL to run it which would fail with an error `Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator`

Comment: In this particular case you can do something like `(from b in DeliverySchedules 
      join c in CustomerOrders on b.CustomerOrderID equals c.ID
      where  dlist.Select(a=>a.DeliveryScheduleID)..Contains(b.id)
      select b.ID).Count();`